# Implementing CRM Features in Micrsoft 365 Exchange Online

Tags: azure, exchange, microsoft-office-365

my Customer wants to migrate from Tobit David to Microsoft 365.
Into David he uses an Feature named "Dv Relatations" where incommung and outgooging emails from all Useres are copied into an seperate archive sorted by the Reciever(incl Out- and In Folder).

What Tools can i using to give my customer this function in Microsoft 365?
Do you have any ressources, that can help my with this task?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, there is no built-in function to fulfill your needs in exchange online side, you may need seek for a 3rd party tool to achieve your goal. I have found a [blog](https://help.mailstore.com/en/server/Archiving_Emails_from_Microsoft_365_(Modern_Authentication)) on your issue for your reference and it may be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. An 3rd Party tool seams to be an Option but all i found are entire CRM Solutions. Mailstore ony archives eMails but dont't sort them by rule or some thing.